# IPBoard user login sessions randomly drops

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, ipb

I have IPBoard running on Nginx `1.10.1` and PHP `7.0.8`. I have an issue where user login sessions randomly drops and sometimes without logging in again the session continues working again. I have tried different session handlers, such as `redis`, but this didn't resolve the issue.

It also seems like once you are randomly logged out, it is only for that page and not for the other pages. So it could also be some faulty caching in IPBoard?

Since I never had any issues with this I think it is IPBoard related. Is there someone who experienced the same and could help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with people using the same IPs, I just had to turn off "Check IP address when validating session?". Hope this helps anyone else with the same problem I had!

[image]